# jtable.org change default table title bakground color

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

The jQuery jtable plugin's default table **title background color** is light blue, how can I change that background color. I am not afaid of changing the CSS template as I am working on a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

In jtable.css search for `div.jtable-main-container > div.jtable-title` and change `background-color`.

```
div.jtable-main-container > div.jtable-title {
  background-color: #428BCA;/* Here you can change color */
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```